# Regex help for Page monitor

Tags: regex, monitoring

- I want to check for the particular text below in a webpage

  ```
  <img class="highlights" src="http://www.carsportal.com/images/highlights/green.jpg">
  ```
- Using this regex for doing so,

  ```
   <img class="highlights" src="[^]*green.jpg">
  ```
- I am trying to monitoring the changes on this webpage using Page Monitor(Chrome extension).  I tested it [here](http://regexr.com/3c8gq).
  But its not working on this extension.

Answer (score 0):

Somethings like this:

```
<img class="highlights" src="[^\"]*green\.jpg">
```